# Having some trouble with getting an automatic import of a Sheet into a Data Table

Tags: google-app-maker

Hoping someone here can help me, I have the below code:

```
    function getSSData(){
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1iKO7j_ETu_x1iJf7y_ih76sDTBS21JULid_5pNIit8w').getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
  var ssData = [];
//   app.datasources.P11d.unload(function(){});
  console.log('Made it to Line 5');
  for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i++){
    var newRecord = app.models.P11d.newRecord();
   // add all fields to the new record
    console.log('Made it to Line 9');
    newRecord.MODEL_FIELD = values[i][0];
    ssData.push(newRecord);
//     console.log(newRecord.MODEL_FIELD);
  }
  console.log('Finished');
// return the array of the model.newRecord objects that would be consumed by the Model query.
  return ssData;
}
```

I have taken this from another post on here, however I can't seem to understand what is happening around the MODEL_FIELD section. Do I need to specify each column title individually or will this just know what to do?

Thank you in advance and I'm sorry if the question seems simple, I'm still very new at this and trying to pick it up as I go along.

Answer (score 1):

values is a 2d array of all of the data in your sheet.

Effectively, the code iterates over all of the rows retrieved from the sheet. For each row a new record is created and the value in the first column of each row is assigned to the field MODEL_FIELD in the new record.

Each new record is pushed into another array which is returned to the caller to be saved with app.saveRecords();

Comment: If a row consists of Timestamp,Email address,Name,Phone,Address line 1 Address line 2,Town,County,Postcode what should the value MODEL_FIELD  = ?